# Matrix Grid Control

Tags: genexus-sd

I am trying to implement a Matrix Grid Control in my project. Trying to follow the instructions:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?HowTo%3A+Using+Matrix+Grid+Control+for+Smart+Devices

I have already created an XAxis (rows), YAxis (columns) and data SDTs, set the properties and fill the data, but no matter what, I always end up with a "Application needs to close" message (Android).
Maybe I'm not doing things right, do you know where I can find a project source to use as a reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of solving the error.

Columns and Headers are still being filled by a SDT (loaded in Start Event).
Replaced the data SDT by a layout var (&valueVar) inside the Matrix Control, being loaded in Load Event.

```
Event Grid1.Load
    &xfrom = 1
    &xto = 1
    &yfrom = 1
    &yto = 1

    &valueVar = 'Value 1'
    LOAD


    &xfrom = 2
    &xto = 2
    &yfrom = 2
    &yto = 2

    &valueVar = 'Value 2'
    LOAD

Endevent
```